# Updating width of hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I am using twitter bootstrap on my responsive website. I have a carousel of image, each with some text over it. I am detecting if the `p` is taller than the carousel and increasing the width where necessary.

```
if ( $(item).find('.carousel-caption')[0].scrollHeight >  $(item).height() && count <= 100) {
    $(item).find('.carousel-caption').css('width', $(item).find('.carousel-caption').width() + 10);
    count++;
    setWidth(item);
}
```

This is ran for each item in the carousel. This works great for the visible (active) item, but not at all for the hidden ones. I have looked into the console and it is the item which has `display: none`.

Is there a way to make this work? It is the `$(item).find('.carousel-caption')[0].scrollHeight` that is retuning 0 for the hidden items.

Comment: Try using `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none`

Comment: Have you tried using the `:hidden` jQuery selector? http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger - It works if I set the item to `$(item).css('display', 'inline-block').css('visibility', 'hidden');` before the `if`, and reset it afterwards: `$(item).css('display', '').css('visibility', 'visible');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with `display:none` are removed from the displayed DOM entirely, so you can't perform many measurements on them. Try changing them from `display:none` to `visibility:hidden` instead so they still take up space.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(item).find('.carousel-caption:hidden')[0].scrollHeight
```